# Authorisation for HTML img src on cross origin

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, authorization

I'm trying to load some resource, in this example an image, in an HTML file, that has it's source on another server, which requires a login.
So writing
`<img src="https://somewebsite.com/images/test.png">`
without any form of authorisation provided, will give me a 401 response.
When I request the image e.g. with Postman and set the authorisation header accordingly, the image is loaded.
Embedding the login information directly into the image src like
`<img src="https://username:password@somewebsite.com/images/test.png">`
works perfectly fine too. Though I don't wan't to have sensible information visible in the DOM.
So basically, what I want to achieve is, that the authorisation header is set for the requests invoked by the img elements.

I already tried to do it with a service worker like this

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        navigator.serviceWorker
        .register('/service-worker.js')
        .then(registration => {
            console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
        });
    });
}
```

with the service-worker.js containing

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
      fetch(event.request, {
          mode: 'cors',
          credentials: 'omit',
          headers: {
              "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa('cui-test:cui-testcui-test')
          }
      })
  )
});
```

though that solution only works if the image's URL is hosted on the same server, not cross origin.
I'm wondering if there is any way to configure a service workers scope to another server.
Or a completely different way to set the header on all requests.